# identify top data and copy rows data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to identify the top 10% value and copy the row data to another sheet in excel using VBA

```
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

    Set myrange = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b1:b1000")
myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlnon

For Each mycell In myrange
   For i = 1 To 2
      If mycell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(myrange, i) Then
           Rows(mycell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
           mycell.Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:= _
               Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a1").Offset(Worksheets("sheet2").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      End If
   Next
Next mycell
   
End Sub
```

The vba code didn't copy my top rows to another sheet

Comment: Do you have a sample of the sheet , maybe an image? Its hard to tell why your code would not work without an example

Comment: Example : myrange value = 1,2,3,5,4. At the 4th iteration, looped cell value is 5. Then in i 1st iteration it check if 5 is the first largest value in 1,2,3,5,4 - because it's yes then the result in sheet2 is 5. Then at the fifth iteration, looped cell value is 4.  At first i iteration it check if 4 is the first largest value in 1,2,3,5,4 - because it's not it goes to the second i iteration and check if 4 is the second largest value in 1,2,3,5,4 - because it's yes then it write under the previous result in sheet2. Please CMIIW.